# Kubernetes - one of the containers to act as a proxy to the main app in a pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have two apps - one is a java based REST application (“A”) and the other one is a go lang based rego policy framework (“B”).

I have run these two apps as containers in a single pod in K8s. However, I am not sure how can I get the incoming HTTP requests to first hit the “B” rego policy framework and based on the policy decision, the request be forwarded to “A”. Is there a way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure how can I get the incoming HTTP requests to first hit the “B” rego policy framework

A "rego policy framework", e.g. OpenPolicyAgent are typically used as an assisting container.

In this setup, your application receives the request, then **ask** the "rego policy framework" container, "is this request allowed?", then your application continue to process the request.

See e.g [OpenPolicyAgent example - HTTP API Authorization](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/http-api-authorization/) with this part, to **ask if the request is allowed**.

```
# ask OPA for a policy decision
# (in reality OPA URL would be constructed from environment)
rsp = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8181/v1/data/httpapi/authz", json=input_dict)
if rsp.json()["allow"]:
  # HTTP API allowed
else:
  # HTTP API denied
```